# recursive generating functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

\begin{align} 
f(0) & = 1 \\
f(1) & = 1 \\ 
f(2) & = 2 \\ 
f(2n) & = f(n)+f(n+1), \;\;\;n\gt1 \\ 
f(2n+1) & = f(n-1)+f(n), \;\;\;n\ge1  \\ 
\end{align}

I am trying to figure out the generating function $G(x)$ for these given parameters, but am not sure how to proceed. I know for the fibonacci series, you just define a function $G(x) = f_0 + f_1x + ... $ and manipulate that so that each term has the appropriate summations, but for this, it doesnt seem so simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $f(x)$ intended as a function on reals, or just as a sequence i.e. a function on $\mathbb{N}$? Generating functions make sense for the latter but not the former.

Comment: Have you tried simple things like $$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } a_nx^n$$ and then use $x=0$ to deduce $f(1)=0$ or $f(1)=f(-1)+f(0)$ and so on?

Comment: Unfortunately the `align` environment doesn't work if it contains empty lines. Did you see that there's a preview under the edit window that allows you to avoid such major formatting failures?

Comment: Calculate the first few terms, and look it up at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: @Semiclassical I think it is safe to assume here that $f(n)$ is intended to be a sequence so I went ahead and edited the question.

Comment: Have you followed up on my suggestion, 3745593?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I decided to check it myself. The first 10 terms of the above sequence are 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6, 4, 7, 6, 9 which doesn't match anything in OEIS. But if one instead takes the first three terms to be 1,0,1 then the sequence obtained appears to match [A051274](https://oeis.org/A051274).

Answer (score 1):

For $n\gt 1$ we have  $$\begin{cases}f(2n)=f(n)+f(n+1)\\f(2(n+1)+1)=f(n)+f(n+1)\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\boxed {f(2n)=f(2n+3)}$$ It follows $$G(x)=(1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^5)+\sum_{n\gt 1}a_{2n}(x^{2n}+x^{2n+3})$$ where I have calculated the coefficients $2,3$ of $x^3,x^5$ respectively.

We need the coefficients $a_4,a_6,a_8,...,a_{2n},…$  for which it holds 
the property
$$a_{2n+2}-a_{2n}\in \{1,2\}$$
If someone wants to finish go ahead. I have no time now.